# Firebase iOS Unity stuck at "Converting managed assemblies to C++"

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

My build works fine without Firebase, but when I try to build with Firebase it get stuck at "Converting managed assemblies to C++".

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you at least give some code sample which gives you an error?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas Download Firebase SDK for Unity ios > Make a build. It gives error

Comment: I am not willing to download anything. You should provide proper information about problem that people could solve it without downloading anything.

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas That's what I mentioned, when I download > install and try to build for ios, Unity stucks at that error. I have not added any code or script from my end.

Comment: This may be stating the obvious but you can't just download and build it. You need to add it to an existing Firebase project that has an attached bundle identifier. Try [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup). I'm only stating this because it's very unclear in the question what steps were taken.